# chemplants: fill the default pictures with TikZ options

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, packages, tikz-styles, fill

The `chemplants` package offers tools to draw simple or barely complex schemes of chemical processes. Process units and styles for streams and utilities are defined to be a sort of extension of the TikZ package, thus a basic knowledge of the logic of this powerful tool is required to profitably use `chemplants`.

Since this package is based on TikZ, its options should be valid. But if I try to pass `fill=gray!25` as a parameter, it doesn't work. Below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{viola}{HTML}{8100FF}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{chemplants}
\renewcommand{\dim}[1]{\left[\mathrm{#1}\right]}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic[xscale = 1.50 ,yscale = 2.50, fill=gray!25] (R) at (0 ,0) { tank reactor };
                    
        \node[xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm] (topright) at (R-anchor) {};

        \pic (het) at (3,1) { heat exchanger };
        \draw[-stealth] (2.5,1) --++ (-1.3,0);      
        \draw[dotted] (-1.2,1.25) --++ (2.4,0);
        \draw[dotted] (-1.2,0.75) --++ (2.4,0);
        
        \pic (heb) at (3,-1) { heat exchanger };
        \draw[-stealth] (2.5,-1) --++ (-1.3,0);     
        \draw[dotted] (-1.2,-1.25) --++ (2.4,0);
        \draw[dotted] (-1.2,-0.75) --++ (2.4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please accept the answers you receive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The majority of elements provided by the `chemplants` package is defined as `\pic`. You cannot style a `\pic` in the same way like a node, because a `\pic` is, so to say, a scoped mini `tikzpicture`.

(In fact, you *can* style a `\pic` like a node if it uses the key `pic actions`. But the `\pic`s defined in this package don't use this key. Thanks to Qrrbrbirlbel for this annotation.)

However, after having looked into the scource code of the package, it seems that almost all the `\pic`s defined in the package use a certain option, namely `chpunitstyle`, for the main `\draw` command of each `\pic`, which is used to set the line thickness and scaling.

For example the `tank reactor` is defined as follows:

```
\tikzset{tank reactor/.pic=%
    {%
    \draw [chpunitstyle]
        (-0.8,-0.732) to [out=270, in=270]
        (0.8,-0.732) --
        (0.8,0.732) to [out=90, in=90]
        (-0.8,0.732) -- cycle;
    \begin{scope} [scale=\chp@UnitScale]
        \coordinate (-anchor) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (-left) at (-0.8,0);
        \coordinate (-bottom left) at (-0.8,-0.732);
        \coordinate (-bottom) at (0,-1.2);
        \coordinate (-bottom right) at (0.8,-0.732);
        \coordinate (-right) at (0.8,0);
        \coordinate (-top right) at (0.8,0.732);
        \coordinate (-top) at (0,1.2);
        \coordinate (-top left) at (-0.8,0.732);
    \end{scope}
    }%
}
```

You can therefore append custom styles to this option using, for example, `chpunitstyle/.append style={fill=gray!25}`. Of course, using this trick, you would only be able to style the element with this key. To style more complex `\pic`s, this approach might not work.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemplants}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic[xscale = 1.50, yscale = 2.50, chpunitstyle/.append style={fill=gray!25}] (R) at (0,0) { tank reactor };
                    
        \node[xshift=1cm, yshift=1cm] (topright) at (R-anchor) {};

        \pic (het) at (3,1) { heat exchanger };
        \draw[-stealth] (2.5,1) -- ++(-1.3,0);      
        \draw[dotted] (-1.2,1.25) -- ++(2.4,0);
        \draw[dotted] (-1.2,0.75) -- ++(2.4,0);
        
        \pic (heb) at (3,-1) { heat exchanger };
        \draw[-stealth] (2.5,-1) -- ++(-1.3,0);     
        \draw[dotted] (-1.2,-1.25) -- ++(2.4,0);
        \draw[dotted] (-1.2,-0.75) -- ++(2.4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "You cannot style a `\pic` in the same way like a node …" One could if the pic definition  would contain `pic actions` (e.g. `\draw[chpunitstyle, pic actions]`). :(